# The number of real roots of the equation $ 1+\frac{x}{1}+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{3}+\dots+\frac{x^{7}}{7}=0$

Tags: real-analysis

The number of real roots of the equation $$ 1+\frac{x}{1}+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{3}+\dots+\frac{x^{7}}{7}=0$$

applying Descartes sign rule I am getting 0 positve roots and 7 negative roots!.
But the answer is 1. How to proceed?

Comment: Descartes rule of signs says that there are at most $7$ negative roots, and that the number of roots is odd.

Comment: so how to proceed for this type of prblem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no positive roots, and Descartes' rule of signs gives the existence of a negative root.  If there were two negative roots, there would be a zero of the derivative between them.  The derivative is $$\frac{x^7-1}{x-1}$$ and has no real zeros.

Or more simply, since the derivative never vanishes and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$, there must be exactly one real zero, which must be negative, since it obviously isn't positve.